# How do I get Emacs to accept a # (hash) sign as a comment starter in a new mode?

Tags: comment, syntax-table

I am attempting to develop an Emacs major mode for writing Tecplot macros. The Tecplot macro language has lots of peculiar constructs, such as a `#` sign for comments and `$!` for the beginning of a macro command. When I use the following code to define the syntax table, I get an invalid character error for the comments:

```el
(defconst tecplot-macro-mode-syntax-table
  (let ((table (make-syntax-table)))
    ;; ' is a string delimiter
    (modify-syntax-entry ?' "\"" table)
    ;; " is a string delimiter too
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\" "\"" table)
    ;; " is a string delimiter too
    (modify-syntax-entry ?| "|" table)

    ;; / is punctuation, but # is a comment starter
    (modify-syntax-entry ?# ". 1b" table)
    table))
```

The error I get is:

```
**Lisp error: (error "Invalid syntax description letter: #")**
```

How do I get the `#` sign to be resolved as a comment? Am I going to have similar issues with the `$!`?

Comment: Derive a new mode from another, similar mode using `define-derived-mode`: don't build it from scratch. E.g. python uses `#` for comments. It may not be the best one to use, but you can see how it does it.

Comment: I don't see how you would get this error for this code. Are you sure it wasn't a slightly different version of the code? `". 1b"` isn't what you want since it declares that `#` is the start of a two-character comment sequence (like `/` in C where comments are `/*…*/`), but it's valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stefan beat me with his answer. Nevertheless, I have got a basis for you where you can start with:

```el
(defconst tecplot-macro-mode-syntax-table
  (let ((table (make-syntax-table)))
    ;; ' is a string delimiter
    (modify-syntax-entry ?' "\"" table)
    ;; " is a string delimiter too
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\" "\"" table)
    ;; |...| delimits variable names
    (modify-syntax-entry ?| "_" table)
    ;; $!... delimits macro calls
    (modify-syntax-entry ?$ "_" table)
    (modify-syntax-entry ?! "_" table)

    ;; / is punctuation, but # is a comment starter
    (modify-syntax-entry ?# "<" table)
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\n ">" table)
    table))

(defvar tecplot-macro-mode-keywords
  '(("$![[:alpha:]]+" . font-lock-function-name-face)
    ("|\\(?:[[:alpha:]]\\|\\s_\\)+|" . font-lock-variable-name-face))
  "List of keywords for `tecplot-macro-mode'.")

(define-derived-mode tecplot-macro-mode prog-mode "Tecplot"
  "Mode for editing Tecplot macros."
  :syntax-table tecplot-macro-mode-syntax-table
  (setq font-lock-defaults '(tecplot-macro-mode-keywords))
  (font-lock-mode)
  )
```

Comment: The `:syntax` keyword seems redundant.  And please don't forcefully emnable `font-lock-mode` from the major.  It's enabled by default anyway, so there's no point making life more difficult for those who explicitly disable font-lock.

Answer (score 1):

Use `?\#` instead of `?#`.  This won't be needed for `!` nor `$` because these chars happen not be special for Elisp, whereas `#` is special (e.g. it is used for hexadecimal numbers like `#xFF`), but you *can* also use `?\!` and it won't hurt.

BTW, if `|...|` is a string, you can use `"\""` rather than `"|"` as its syntax (BTW, there's a copy&paste error in your comment about `|`).

The `1b` says that `#` is the first char of a two-chars comment starter (e.g. if a comment starter takes the form `#|` then you'd put a `2` into the syntax of `|`), but in your case it seems like you just want to use `"<"` for `?\#`.

Comment: I tried the ?\# in the second argument, and that works providing I do not use any form of # in the third argument, such as ```(modify-syntax-entry ?\# "\#" table)```. I tried different options for the third argument, and found ```"<"``` to be the only option that doesn't produce an error. But with this, the $! is seen as  comment, not a command.

Comment: Hi Stefan. `?#` works. It is even in the Elisp manual. See the ["defvar lisp-mode-syntax-table" example.](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Example-Major-Modes.html)